# Use Binomial theorem to simplify $\sum_{k=0}^{16}(-1)^k\binom{16}k (3)^{16-k}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

When I simplified it out to equal $(x + y)^{n}$ which is $(3 - 1)^{16}$ or **65,536**. Is that correct or have I messed up somewhere?

I hope my question even comes out right, I did my best with the mathjax but I can't see the output of my title (n on top of the sum is 16, but I couldnt get a 2 digit number to fit on top)

$$\sum_{k=0}^{16}(-1)^k\binom{16}k (3)^{16-k}$$

Comment: There is a slight problem. What is the upper bound of your summation? You have it as $n$ but the summation itself suggests $16$.

Comment: Oh I see now. For the record if you want to include multiple things (or anything more than one character long) in MathJax like that, you can use brackets. For example, `\sum_{k=0}^{16}` renders as $$\sum_{k=0}^{16}$$

Comment: @Evee Trainer    It's 16, I just couldn't get the 16 to work when I was making the equation with mathjax, it kept messing it up so I just put an n there. Edit: Oh okay, thanks for for letting me know about the brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the binomial theorem:

$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k a^k b^{n-k}$$

Take $a = -1, b=3,n=16$: then

$$(-1+3)^{16} = \sum_{k=0}^{16} \binom {16} k (-1)^k 3^{16-k}$$

which is identical to your sum and simplifies to $2^{16}$ as claimed.

---

In short, yes, you're correct. I just hope that writing it as I have above can resolve any doubts. If absolutely nothing else, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D0+to+16+C%2816%2Ck%29+*+%28-1%29%5Ek+*+3%5E%2816-k%29) also agrees with us.